# Synchronising method evaluation based on value

Tags: java, concurrency

Let's say I have a method which calculates factorial for a number. Now this is a cpu intensive task, so if 1 of my thread is already calculating factorial for a number i should not call the factorial method for same value again. How can this be achieved using locking? And since factorial values don't change (unless the definition does :) ), I would put the calculated values in a map.
Map.get() should not be locking but only when we have to do the calculation and put in map we should use locking.

(The Factorial is just and example it could be a http call which is waiting for io response.)

Comment: Why should `get` not be locking? It is a map that is shared by many threads, where they write to and read from it. It *must* be locked or synchronized in any other way.

Comment: read should not be locking for higher performance, write should only be allowed by the above mechanism, where for 1 key only 1 thread is running and others are waiting on 1st thread's result.

Comment: Yes, but again: "It is a map that is shared by many threads, where they write to and read from it. It must be locked or synchronized in any other way." Another thing: Why should the other threads wait for the one new factorial? What if they all calculate the factorial for a different key? You would effectively slow down your app like that. Of course there's the chance that the key of a waiting thread is the same as the calculated one, but 1 key compared to an infinite amount of other possible keys makes it much more unlikely.

Comment: read should be done in nonblocking way, but write is done only the optimised way.
All the request for same key of factorial should wait for existing running factorial, but all the different factorial keys should be calculated independently.

Comment: we will not be exposing the map to all the threads, we will only expose a method getFactorial(); which gets from hashmap or call factorial(). in factorial() method all the threads `for same value` are blocked and only 1 thread is allowed to proceed.

Comment: You should check out [`ConcurrentHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html), it's really good here. Then programming the caching mechanism itself becomes pretty simple.

Comment: it is only about concurrency control while inserting and getting, it does not have support for only making one call, when multiple get are done for same value.

Comment: you can use guava cache to implement this behavuiour, there is loadingCache class, which will take care of this behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Guava loadingCache for this.

this is how the code looks like

```
LoadingCache<Integer, Employee> empCache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
       .maximumSize(100)
       .expireAfterWrite(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
       .build(
           new CacheLoader<Integer, Employee>() {
        @Override
        public Employee load(Integer id) throws Exception {
            //heavy operation here
            return getEmployeeById(id);
        }
           }
       );
```

If multiple thread do a get for same key, getEmployeeById will be called only once.